# Error sending JSON to database

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

I'm trying to send some information to the database. It's looks ok no errors but no data is sent to the database,  and i'm getting this message from the server  I/Create Response(2026): {"message":"Required field(s) is missing","success":0}.
I tried to find a solution from similar posts, but no luck.

Thanks in advance!

```
java code:


public class AddRecipeActivity extends Activity {

private ImageView imageView;
private Button buttonNewPic;
private Button buttonImage;
private Bitmap image;
private static final int IMAGE_PICK     = 1;
private static final int IMAGE_CAPTURE  = 2;
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();


EditText AddRecipeTitleEditText; //title
EditText AddIngredientsEditTextMultiLine; // ingrediants
EditText AddDirectionsEditTextMultiLine; // directions
EditText Add_spinner; //catagory
EditText AddImageView ; //image

// url to create new product
private static String url_create_recipe = "http://studentcookbook.comoj.com/android_connect/create_recipe.php";


// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

Spinner spnr;
String[] Category = {
        " - - - - - - Select Category - - - - - - ",
        "chicken",
        "meat",
        "fish",
        "pasta",
        "salad",
        "soup"
};
public ProgressDialog pDialog;
public String TAG_SCB_ID;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_recipe);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }
    //testaddimageView
    this.imageView      = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.AddImageView);
    this.buttonNewPic   = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.CameraButton);
    this.buttonImage    = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.GalleryButton);

    AddRecipeTitleEditText=(EditText)           findViewById(R.id.AddRecipeTitleEditText);//title
    AddIngredientsEditTextMultiLine= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.AddIngredientsEditTextMultiLine);// ingrediants
    AddDirectionsEditTextMultiLine=(EditText)   findViewById(R.id.AddDirectionsEditTextMultiLine);//Dirctions


    spnr = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.Add_spinner);//category

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Category);
    spnr.setAdapter(adapter);

    this.buttonImage.setOnClickListener(new ImagePickListener());
    this.buttonNewPic.setOnClickListener(new TakePictureListener());// Create button
    Button btnCreateProduct = (Button) findViewById(R.id.AddSubmitButton1);

    // button click event
    btnCreateProduct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // creating new product in background thread
            new CreateNewProduct().execute();
        }
    });

}


/**
 * Background Async Task to Create new product
 * */
class CreateNewProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AddRecipeActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Creating Product..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        String isLoaded;
        String title= AddRecipeTitleEditText.getText().toString();

        String ingrediants = AddIngredientsEditTextMultiLine.getText().toString();

        String description = AddDirectionsEditTextMultiLine.getText().toString();

        //  String catagory = Add_spinner.getText().toString();

        //  String image = AddImageView.getText().toString();


        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_recipe,
                "POST", params);
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("title", title));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ingrediants", ingrediants));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("description", description));
        //params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("catagory", catagory));
        //  params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image", image));

        // getting JSON Object
        // Note that create product url accepts POST method


        if(json!=null){
            // do something

            // check log cat fro response
            Log.i("Create Response", json.toString());

            // check for success tag
            try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // successfully created product
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AddRecipeActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "working fine", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    isLoaded = "Success";
                    // closing this screen
                    finish();
                } else {
                    // failed to create product
                    isLoaded = "failed";
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }}
        return null;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once done
        pDialog.dismiss();
        //          if(file_url.equals("Success")) {
        //              // success: launch another activity
        //              Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AddRecipeActivity.class);
        //              startActivity(i);
        //              AddRecipeActivity.this.finish();
        //          } else if(file_url.equals("Failed")) {
        //              // failed: do something
        //              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "An error occurred...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //          }


    }
}


protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) { 
        switch (requestCode) {
        case IMAGE_PICK:    
            this.imageFromGallery(resultCode, data);
            break;
        case IMAGE_CAPTURE:
            this.imageFromCamera(resultCode, data);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Update the imageView with new bitmap
 * @param newImage
 */
private void updateImageView(Bitmap newImage) {
    BitmapProcessor bitmapProcessor = new BitmapProcessor(newImage, 300, 300, 0);

    this.image = bitmapProcessor.getBitmap();
    this.imageView.setImageBitmap(this.image);
}

/**
 * Image result from camera
 * @param resultCode
 * @param data
 */
private void imageFromCamera(int resultCode, Intent data) {
    this.updateImageView((Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"));
}

/**
 * Image result from gallery
 * @param resultCode
 * @param data
 */
private void imageFromGallery(int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
    String [] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
    String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
    cursor.close();

    this.updateImageView(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath));
}

/**
 * Click Listener for selecting images from phone gallery
 * @author tscolari
 *
 */
class ImagePickListener implements OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Escolha uma Foto"), IMAGE_PICK);

    }
}

/**
 * Click listener for taking new picture
 * @author tscolari
 *
 */
class TakePictureListener implements OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    }
}
```

}

php code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
/*
 * Following code will create a new product row
 * All product details are read from HTTP Post Request
 */
    error_reporting(0);
// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// check for required fields
if (isset($_POST['title'])&& isset($_POST['ingredients'])&& isset($_POST['directions'])&&    isset($_POST['category'])) {

$title = $_POST['title'];
$ingredients = $_POST['ingredients'];
$directions = $_POST['directions'];
   $category = $_POST['category'];
print_r($_POST);
// include db connect class
define('__ROOT__', dirname(dirname(__FILE__))); 
require_once(__ROOT__.'/android_connect/db_connect.php'); 

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

// mysql inserting a new row
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO scb( title, ingredients, directions, category ) VALUES('$title',   '$ingredients', '$directions', '$category')");

// check if row inserted or not
if ($result) {
    // successfully inserted into database
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "Recipe successfully created.";
             $response["id"] = mysql_insert_id();
    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    // failed to insert row
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
} else {
// required field is missing
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

// echoing JSON response
echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

logact error message:

```
 10-30 00:56:29.695: E/AndroidRuntime(2245): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
 10-30 00:56:29.695: E/AndroidRuntime(2245): Process: com.example.studentcookbook, PID: 2245
10-30 00:56:29.695: E/AndroidRuntime(2245): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while   executing doInBackground()
10-30 00:56:29.695: E/AndroidRuntime(2245):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
10-30 00:56:29.695: E/AndroidRuntime(2245):     at    java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
10-30 00:56:29.695: E/AndroidRuntime(2245):     at    java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
10-30 00:56:29.695: E/AndroidRuntime(2245):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
10-30 00:56:29.695: E/AndroidRuntime(2245):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
10-30 00:56:29.695: E/AndroidRuntime(2245):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
10-30 00:56:29.695: E/AndroidRuntime(2245):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
10-30 00:56:29.695: E/AndroidRuntime(2245):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
10-30 00:56:29.695: E/AndroidRuntime(2245): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-30 00:56:29.695: E/AndroidRuntime(2245):     at   com.example.studentcookbook.AddRecipeActivity$CreateNewProduct.doInBackground(AddRecipeActivity.java:146)
10-30 00:56:29.695: E/AndroidRuntime(2245):     at com.example.studentcookbook.AddRecipeActivity$CreateNewProduct.doInBackground(AddRecipeActivity.java:1)
10-30 00:56:29.695: E/AndroidRuntime(2245):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
10-30 00:56:29.695: E/AndroidRuntime(2245):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
10-30 00:56:29.695: E/AndroidRuntime(2245):     ... 4 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

category is a required parameter

In you Java code I see:
//params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("catagory", catagory));

Commented out, but also with a typo on catagory instead of category

Answer (score 1):

'ingrediants' != 'ingredients'

'catagory' != 'category'

The items you're posting and the items the script is looking for don't match.

Comment: I fixed it, but now i have FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2 error please see edited version for logcat error message

Comment: I don't really know java, but just in looking at it I don't see a definition anywhere for the 'getApplicationContext()' call (though maybe that's global / somewhere else), which might generate an error like that if it returns a null pointer?